# ERROR: syntax error at or near "DELIMITER" LINE 1: DELIMITER //

Tags: postgresql, triggers

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_stockmgmt_stock_update//
CREATE TRIGGER after_stockmgmt_stock_update AFTER UPDATE ON stockmgmgt_stock FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.issue_quantity = 0 
        THEN INSERT INTO stockmgmgt_stockhistory(
            id, 
            last_updated, 
            category_id, 
            item_name, 
            quantity, 
            receive_quantity, 
            receive_by) 
        VALUES(
            new.id, 
            new.last_updated, 
            new.category_id, 
            new.item_name, 
            new.quantity, 
            new.receive_quantity, 
            new.receive_by);

    ELSEIF new.receive_quantity = 0 
        THEN INSERT INTO stockmgmgt_stockhistory(
            id, 
            last_updated, 
            category_id, 
            item_name, 
            issue_quantity, 
            issue_to, 
            issue_by, 
            quantity) 
        VALUES(
            new.id, 
            new.last_updated, 
            new.category_id, 
            new.item_name, 
            new.issue_quantity, 
            new.issue_to, 
            new.issue_by, 
            new.quantity);
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Wrong copy/paste or what is the question?

Comment: `delimiter` isn't a valid [SQL command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) in Postgres. And the [syntax for triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER) is also completely different